# Laggy switching between fragments using a drawerlayout - android

Tags: android

I'm encountering slow/laggy behaviour when swithcing between frgaments using a drawerlayout. I've read up here on stackoverflow and elsewhere regarding solving this issue and a major piece of advice e.g. as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545655/custom-android-tabhost-slow-fragments) is to populating bits of fragment related views elsewhere hence my question of how best can one do the populating part outside of onCreateView() to avoid the laggy behaviour.

Any help is appreciated.

My code is as follows:

My main activity below:

```
/*!  Main activity class */
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FragListener {

    /** Private vars */
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView lvDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private CharSequence drawerTitle;
    private CharSequence title;
    private DrawerLayoutAdapter drawerLayoutAdapter;
    private List<DrawerLayoutDrawer> lvDrawerLayoutData;    

    /** Public vars */
    public static String TAG = "MainActivity";    
    public MainActivity mainActivity;
    public Display display;
    public Typeface officialBoldFont, officialRegularFont;
    public TextView actionBarTView, tvActionBarTitle = null;
    public Fragment fragment;

    //!<
    public MainActivity() {

    }

    //!<
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // getTitle() is part of Activity
        title = drawerTitle = getTitle();

        // Obtain the normal device display area 
        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 

        // Set official font
        officialRegularFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "square721extendedreg.ttf"); 
        officialBoldFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "square721extendedbold.ttf"); 

        // Show action bar
        getSupportActionBar().show();

        // Inflate the custom action bar
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View mCustomActionView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);        

        tvActionBarTitle = (TextView) mCustomActionView.findViewById(R.id.tv_action_bar_title);
        tvActionBarTitle.setTypeface(officialBoldFont);
        tvActionBarTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        tvActionBarTitle.setTextSize(14.5f);

        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(mCustomActionView);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xffFFCC00));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        // Inflate and customise the drawer layout
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(new ColorDrawable(0xffFF0000), GravityCompat.START);
        drawerLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_drawerlayout_default);

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_closed) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(drawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };        

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        // Inflate and customise the drawer layout list and drawer layout adapter
        lvDrawerLayout = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_drawer);
        lvDrawerLayout.setDividerHeight(2);

        // Below is the listview's bgnd and is different from bgnd_lv_item_drawerlayout.xml which is the bgnd for the items in this LV
        lvDrawerLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_drawerlayout_default); 

        lvDrawerLayoutData = new ArrayList<DrawerLayoutDrawer>();
        lvDrawerLayoutData.add(new DrawerLayoutDrawer("ADMINISTRATION", R.drawable.ic_test));
        lvDrawerLayoutData.add(new DrawerLayoutDrawer("FINANCE CALCULATOR", R.drawable.ic_test));
        lvDrawerLayoutData.add(new DrawerLayoutDrawer("EXIT", R.drawable.ic_test));

        drawerLayoutAdapter = new DrawerLayoutAdapter(this, R.layout.lv_layout_drawer, lvDrawerLayoutData, officialRegularFont, officialBoldFont);

        lvDrawerLayout.setAdapter(drawerLayoutAdapter);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

        // Call starting fragment
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            callStartingFrag(0);
        }
    }

    //!< Call starting fragment
    public void callStartingFrag(int position) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        fragment = new FragmentOne();
        args.putString(" ", lvDrawerLayoutData.get(position).getItemName());
        args.putInt(" ", lvDrawerLayoutData.get(position).getImgResID());

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        lvDrawerLayout.setItemChecked(position, true);

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(lvDrawerLayout);
    }

    //!< Enable drawer layout
    public void enableDrawerLayout() {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);        
    }

    //!< Set custom action bar title
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title){
        tvActionBarTitle.setText(title);
    }

    //!< Return MainActivity object
    public MainActivity getMainActivity() {
        mainActivity = new MainActivity();

        return mainActivity;
    }

    //!< This hook is called whenever an item in your options menu is selected. . The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer. ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //!<  Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred. Called when activity start-up is complete (after onStart() and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) have been called). Applications will generally not implement this method; it is intended for system classes to do final initialization after application code has run.
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    //!<  Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles. This method should always be called by your Activity's onConfigurationChanged method.
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    //!< Call respective fragment
    public void selectItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            break;                
        case 2:
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        lvDrawerLayout.setItemChecked(position, true);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(lvDrawerLayout);
    }

}
```

Drawer layout code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/content_frame"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#000000"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Drawer layout listview laout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/itemLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_itemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Action bar layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_action_bar_title"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:textSize="15dp"
         android:maxLines="1"
         android:ellipsize="end"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

1st fragment code:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    ImageView ivIcon;
    TextView tvAgentID;
    public Typeface officialBoldFont, officialRegularFont;

    public static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
    public static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";

    public FragmentOne() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container, false);

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).enableDrawerLayout();

        /*dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerLayoutDrawer>();

            dataList.add(new DrawerLayoutDrawer("Frag one list item 1", R.drawable.lv_tempimg2));

            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).changeDrawerList(dataList, new FragOneClickListener());*/

        //
        officialRegularFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "square721extendedreg.ttf"); 
        officialBoldFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "square721extendedbold.ttf"); 

        tvAgentID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_agentid);

        tvAgentID.setText("TESTING 1 2 3");
        tvAgentID.setTypeface(officialBoldFont);
        tvAgentID.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tvAgentID.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        tvAgentID.setTextSize(25f);

        return view;
    }

}
```

1st fragment layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#000000">

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/ll_innerloginlayout"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_margin="20dp"
      android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv_agentid"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

2nd fragment code below:

```
public class FragmentTwo   extends Fragment {

    ImageView ivIcon;
    TextView tvItemName;

    public static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
    public static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";

    private List<DrawerLayoutDrawer> dataList;  

    public FragmentTwo()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_two, container, false);

        //
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Test screen 2");

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).enableDrawerLayout();

        /*dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerLayoutDrawer>();

          dataList.add(new DrawerLayoutDrawer("Frag two list item 2", R.drawable.lv_tempimg2));

          ((MainActivity) getActivity()).changeDrawerList(dataList, new FragTwoClickListener());*/

        ivIcon=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.frag2_icon);
        tvItemName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.frag2_text);

        tvItemName.setText("TESTING FRAG TWO");
        tvItemName.setTextSize(45f);
        tvItemName.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tvItemName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        return view;
    }

}
```

2nd fragment XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <!--
    **************************IMPORTANT***********************************
     change this id attribute values as "frag2_icon" and "frag2_text" for
     fragment_layout_two.xml and "frag3_icon" and "frag3_text" for
     fragment_layout_three.xml
    **********************************************************************
      -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frag2_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/frag2_text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
              android:paddingLeft="12dp"
              android:paddingRight="12dp"
              android:paddingTop="12dp"
              android:paddingBottom="0dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

3rd fragment code:

```
public class FragmentThree extends Fragment {

    ImageView ivIcon;
    TextView tvItemName;

    public static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
    public static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";

    public FragmentThree()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_three, container, false);

        ivIcon=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.frag3_icon);
        tvItemName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.frag3_text);

        tvItemName.setText("TESTING FRAG THREE");
        return view;
    }

}
```

3rd fragment XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <!--
    **************************IMPORTANT***********************************
     change this id attribute values as "frag2_icon" and "frag2_text" for
     fragment_layout_two.xml and "frag3_icon" and "frag3_text" for
     fragment_layout_three.xml
    **********************************************************************
      -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frag3_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frag3_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

1st fragment listener:

```
public class FragOneClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mainActivity = new  MainActivity();

        mainActivity.fragOneSelectItem(position);
    }
}
```

2nd fragment listener:

```
public class FragTwoClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mainActivity = new  MainActivity();

        mainActivity.fragTwoSelectItem(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean about the animation performed by the DrawerLayout?

Comment: have you tried to move some of the code logic outside `onCreate()` ? the "sloppy" animation that you see might be because a lot of stuff happens in `onCreate()`. try to move some logic to `onResume()` or `onStart()`.

Comment: This smells horribly wrong. First, you didn't describe your problem precisely. What is slow, when and where? Second, there are many places in your code where your Activity creates a new instance of itself. Why? It's not clear to me, at all. Looks like you have many problems at once.